# converting a string like '{100-101:[405-874, 405-863], 100-100:[405-862, 405-865]} to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am trying to convert a string type to its equivalent Dictionary form:

```
sample_str='{100-101:[405-874, 405-863], 100-100:[405-862, 405-865]}'
dict_str=json.loads(sample_str)
```

Error:

```
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"
```

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like…? Why do you have this string, which doesn't appear to be any sort of standard format, in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it,

Type 1:
Considering the input format is correct which you have mentioned, then the code is

```
import yaml
s = '{100-101:[405-874, 405-863], 100-100:[405-862, 405-865]}'
d = yaml.load(s, Loader=yaml.Loader)
d
```

[image]

Type 2: The usual way
Here, the input has to be modified slightly to make it string key: value pair
e.g. test_string = '{"100-101":"[405-874, 405-863]", "100-100":"[405-862, 405-865]"}'

Then the code is

```
import json
test_string = '{"100-101":"[405-874, 405-863]", "100-100":"[405-862, 405-865]"}'
print("The original string : " + str(test_string))
res = json.loads(test_string)
res
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I needed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_str='{"100-101":["405-874", "405-863"], "100-100":["405-862", "405-865"]}' 
dict_str=json.loads(sample_str)
```

You need to add the keys as strings in double quotes.

Comment: yes ,Thank you for your response,                                                                                             but can you suggest me how to do it automatically, without putting the quotes manually?